# Apache Airflow : airflow initdb throws ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'wtforms.compat'

Tags: python, airflow

On Ubuntu 21.04 with python 3.9, trying to install airflow. When I ran airflow init db command, below error is thrown

> File "", line 855, in
> exec_module   File "", line 228, in
> *call_with_frames_removed   File "/home/user/USB/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/airflow/migrations/versions/82b7c48c147f_remove_can_read_permission_on_config*.py",
> line 29, in 
> from airflow.www.app import create_app   File "/home/user/USB/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/airflow/www/app.py",
> line 24, in 
> from flask_appbuilder import SQLA   File "/home/user/USB/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask_appbuilder/**init**.py",
> line 6, in 
> from .base import AppBuilder  # noqa: F401   File "/home/user/USB//.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask_appbuilder/base.py",
> line 8, in 
> from .api.manager import OpenApiManager   File "/home/user/USB//.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask_appbuilder/api/manager.py",
> line 8, in 
> from flask_appbuilder.baseviews import BaseView   File "/home/user/USB//.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask_appbuilder/baseviews.py",
> line 21, in 
> from .forms import GeneralModelConverter   File "/home/user/USB//.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask_appbuilder/forms.py",
> line 16, in 
> from .fields import EnumField, QuerySelectField, QuerySelectMultipleField   File
> "/home/user/USB//.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask_appbuilder/fields.py",
> line 6, in 
> from wtforms.compat import string_types, text_type

I tried installing wtforms separately.

airflow was installing with pipenv

Any idea?

thanks

Answer (score 3):

Just install airflow including constraints files as explained in installation documentation.

Airflow has complex dependencies and specific way of installation and in order to install it.in consistent way, you need to use constraints.

https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/installation.html#installation-script

Answer (score 2):

Try to use version 2.3.3 for WTForms and its compatible version marshmallow for example 2.21.0. I added this at the begging of my requirements.txt

```
marshmallow==2.21.0
WTForms==2.3.3
```

Comment: I ran into a WTForms issue last week and ended up with the same solution.